# Test redirection Spring

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, redirect, spring-test

I can't find accurate information about testing a redirection. I've read over a dozen posts here including spring boot testing documentation.

When I test my controller with POST I got HTTP 200 status code and it is fine.

But my question is that is it possible to catch 302 status during performance it or I have to do it as integration test or otherwise?

Model

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserDTO {

    @NotBlank(message = "Username is mandatory.")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 15)
    private String userName;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "First name is mandatory.")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 15)
    private String firstName;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Last name is mandatory.")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
    private String lastName;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "An email is mandatory.")
    @Email
    @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
    private String email;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "A password is mandatory.")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
    private String password;
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/sign-up")
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("userDTO") @Valid UserDTO userDTO, Errors errors) {
        
        if(errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "sign-up";
        }
        
        userService.addUser(userDTO);
        return "redirect:/successful-sign-up";
    }
```

Test

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(BasicTemplatesController.class)
@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled = true)
public class UserControllerTest {
    
    @MockBean
    private UserController userController;
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should correctly add user and return HTTP status FOUND.")
    void shouldCorrectlyAddUserAndReturnCreated() throws Exception {
        
        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO( 
                "Username", 
                "New", 
                "User", 
                "new@gmail.com", 
                "password");

        mvc.perform(post("/sign-up")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(userDTO))
                )
            .andExpect(status().isFound());
        
    }
```

Comment: You aren't testing anything due to the `@MockBean` of `UserController`. Your `@WebMVcTest` should use `UserController` not `BasicTemplatesController` nor should you use the mockito extension. Also your test doesn't make sense (sending json as a form).